# ASP.net build error: Identifier '__ASP' is not CLS-compliant

Tags: asp.net, cls-compliant

i am getting error when building an ASP.net web-site:

> Identifier '__ASP' is not CLS-compliant

Nowhere in my code is there the identifier `__ASP`.

> i know *why* `__ASP` is not CLS-compliant (it starts with an `_`). What i need to figure out who is emitting it, and how either:
>
> - change it to not start with an underscore, or
> - make it private
>
> i could also stop marking the assembly as CLSCompliant - but i'm not gonna

The warning does not list any useful file:

```
4d48b87d\63ccbbb9\App_Code.x0tl4q2v.49.cs line 15
```

Which is, obviously, not a file i created. How can i identify where this `__ASP` identifier is, and remove it, or make it private?

---

i'm not  the only person experiencing __ASP problems:

- [Removing the "warning CS3008: Identifier '__ASP' is not CLS-compliant" warning](http://www.fishofprey.com/2009/02/removing-warning-cs3008-identifier-asp.html)
- [warning CS3008: Identifier '__ASP' is not CLS-compliant](http://forums.asp.net/t/1201507.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "__ASP" files are created by the runtime ASP.NET compiler that converts *.aspx, *.ascx, *.master files into .NET classes that derive from your CodeBehind classes (or in MVC, from your ViewPage classes). The compiler build system also compiles your `App_Code` files at runtime (as opposed to compiling them from within the IDE).

However, you shouldn't get CLS-compliancy messages in ASP.NET applications unless you've added the [CLSCompliant] attribute to your assembly somewhere. Do you have an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, if so, where is it?

EDIT:

I just saw that you said your assembly is marked as CLSCompliant. Well, that's your problem. You need to remove it because ASP.NET's batch-compiled files are not compliant: they don't need to be. Terminal assemblies (i.e. those not referenced by other assemblies, usually because they are the "application" assemblies) do not need to be CLSCompliant.

Why do you say you're "not gonna" remove the attribute? It isn't inappropriate to not have it.

Comment: Shared code contains `CLSCompliant` attributes. Those attributes throw errors if the web-site is not marked with a `CLSCompliant` attribute. But i realized now that just because i ***have*** to have a `[CLSCompliant]` attribute, it doesn't ***have*** to be `[CLSCompliant(true)]`. i changed it to `[CLSCompliant(false)]` and it works now. It's useful to know that ASP.net itself is not cls compliant (helps to justify disabling compliance).